# Remove HTML tags in <input> on keypress

Tags: jquery, html, input, replace

I made a code and it's working fine to remove HTML tags in `<input>` by jQuery

```
$("input").on("keypress",function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var open = val.indexOf('<');
    var close = val.indexOf('>');
    if(open!==-1 && close!==-1) {
      $(this).val(val.replace(val.slice(open,close+1),""));
    }
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/uzibey/1/edit

But any better idea or functions should I use ?

PS : No server side security needed , Using in Admin area btw.

Comment: Doing this in JavaScript does nothing for security - a malicious client could just add them again before sending the form.

Comment: Do your input cleaning server side.

Comment: No-security needed , Coz I use this in Admin-area @Pekka웃

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: Does this mean that I can't input x < 20 && x > 2?

Comment: But I can input `><b>works great</b>`

Comment: That why i asked here :D @mindandmedia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the DOM to sanitise your input. Simply create a dummy element (without inserting it into the document) and insert the value of the input using `innerHTML`. Then remove all nodes except text nodes.

This has the benefit of using an actual HTML parser to detect HTML, instead of a regex approximation. Anything that can be interpreted as an HTML element by the browser will be removed.

Here is a very basic demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/uA94h/

EDIT: The above demonstration removes non-text nodes entirely. By request, here is a demonstration where elements are replaced with their text: http://jsfiddle.net/TknBs/.

Comment: I think your answer is better , But I need some demo , thanks :D

Comment: Check the link commented by Christian or in my answer. It has the sample.

Comment: Nice @Asad But can I can from `test <b>one</b>` to `test one` not `test` ?

Comment: @l2aelba Ah, so you want to convert the HTML elements to text?

Comment: @l2aelba It seems to sanitise as soon as you type an opening angle bracket followed by a single character. I guess the reason behind this is that even injecting `<img` into a document creates a complete image tag, since browsers are fault tolerant.

Comment: I guess this is correct behavior, since you're trying to filter out anything that could be interpreted as HTML, although it is somewhat annoying. If you want, you could use XML parsing to only sanitise when complete tags are found.

Comment: Ok, Its many ways to do... not 100% but its work enough , Thanks so much @Asad

Comment: @l2aelba Here is a demonstration of the XML approach. This works as you would expect: http://jsbin.com/uzibey/7/edit

Comment: @l2aelba What are you typing? I tested it with `<div>Hello</div>`, which it converts to `Hello` on my next keypress.

Comment: @l2aelba Ah yes, I just realised the problem. When passing to parseXML, the entire string must be valid XML. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way around this. For the `<br>` case, it will only sanitise if you use `<br/>`

Comment: But It's ok now , your answers are enough to do :D thanks @Asad

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("input").on("keypress",function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    var result = val .replace(regex, "");
    $(this).val(result);

});
```

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer, if you got your expected output

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex for this

```
<[^>]*(>|$)
```

try applying this one to the input string to see if it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 ways:

One is here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

The other one is this:

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```